# What happens if you enter the incorrect password too often for ktpass command

Tags: linux, passwords, kerberos

I need help with the Kerberos ktpass functionality in regards to incorrectly entering the password multiple times:

What happens if we automate the ktpass command to run in a Linux bash shell "for" loop 20 times but we "fat finger" the password in the script, would that lock out the password?  Would that disable the systems that already have Kerberos configured?

I did search Google and couldn't find anything about ktpass and "lock" password.